# Set toolbar menu items height

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-toolbar, popupmenu

I want to set the height of toolbar menu items.

[image: Set the height of each textView]

I right the below code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:padding="2dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MyDarkToolbarStyle"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar"
        app:titleMarginStart="20dp" />
```

Code for Tablayout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/LightThemeSelector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@color/White"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/Black"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/Black"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/common_signin_btn_light_text_disabled"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Code for Style which is declare in Manifest:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/normalColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/normalColor</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
        <!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Item Height & Property -->
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingRight">5dp</item>
    </style>



<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.

        -->
    </style>
```

My Problem is this code is working for Lolipop. But below Lolipop this is not working. Please guide me what is the problem behind this.